# Always show keyboard shortcuts in Gnome — take effect without a restart

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, dialog

I just discovered that many Gnome dialog boxes do have keyboard shortcuts to reach controls or tabs with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> — only they are not displayed. The shortcuts do appear in the form of an underlined letter when I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> down.

How can I make the shortcut letter always underlined, so that the shortcuts are discoverable? Same question for menu items, by the way.

What I see normally:

[image: no underline]

What I see with <kbd>Alt</kbd> held down, and I want to see all the time:

[image: with underline]

I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103922/gnome-3-always-show-altx-keyboard-shortcuts, which suggests adding `gtk-auto-mnemonic = 0` to `~/.gtkrc-2.0` for Gnome 2 and `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/automatic-mnemonics false` for Gnome 3. Neither seems to have any effect in my session though.

In Ubuntu 12.04, in my sessionafter setting `automatic-mnemonics` to false, shortcut letters still don't appear unless I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> down (I tried in pavucontrol, evince and gnome-control-center). I start my session from Lightdm and **I am not running a Gnome session**. My window manager is Sawfish. I do have a D-Bus daemon, and **other dconf settings take effect immediately** (e.g. `/org/gnome/desktop/background/draw-background`). If I start another session with `startx` on the same machine, the change of `automatic-mnemonics` is not reflected. However, if I run a default (Unity or Gnome) session in a different account, `automatic-mnemonics` takes effect immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The `dconf` method works for me on 12.04. What you may try:

- Are you modifying the `dconf` entry for the same user as with you launch the applications. (e.g. don't use `sudo`) The `dconf` settings are per-user.
- Is your `~/.config/dconf/user` file writeable by your user?
- Maybe that file is corrupted. Try making a backup of the `~/.config/dconf/user` file, and then remove it. Logout, login and then try again the dconf settings with the newly generated file.

Comment: All my other dconf settings work, so I don't see how it could be a dconf issue (and anyway, no, I'm not doing anything weird like running applications as another user).

Comment: @Gilles Have you tried modifying the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml` file directly, changing the appropriate automatic-mnemonics key to false? If this works, then you can make an override file for this, though this will change this preference for every user, which might not be suitable for you.

Comment: Changing `automatic-mnemonics` to `false` in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.interface.gschema.xml` doesn't make any difference (I checked in a new session). I'm not using Cinnamon, I only have official Ubuntu packages installed.

Comment: @Gilles If you change that .xml, you will also have to run `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` to recompile the schemas. But before that: backup the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled` file, just in case, this file will be changed by the recompile. After that you have to logout-login to see the effects.

Comment: This doesn't change anything in my session or in a new session. I tested the normal `dconf write` method and it does work for a fresh account (starting with an empty home). What I haven't tried is logging out completely (maybe my second session was communicating with a D-Bus process from the first session?). I'll do that when I get a chance to log out or fire up a test VM. All other gconf/dconf settings I'd tried took effect immediately, so I wonder why this one would require a completely fresh login (if that turns out to be the issue).

Comment: Apologies for the delay. I've finally had time to test a bit. It seems that the `automatic-mnemonics` setting does work, but it does not apply in my session, not even to newly started Gnome applications in a new session on the same machine. I hadn't suspected that at first because other settings do take effect immediately, I'd never had to restart anything.

Comment: @Gilles Looks like it is a bug (or unimplemented feature) in Sawfish then. I have zero experience with Sawfish, so my knowledge ends here.

Comment: But Sawfish shouldn't have anything to do! I'm running the Gnome configuration program and a Gnome application. The window manager should not matter.

Comment: @Gilles OK. I don't know how is this handled, which applications responsibility is to detect/implement the change. (I think you are right though, the WM shouldn't have any effect on this.) But following normal inductive logic would dictate that it is a problem in Sawfish, since everything else is the same in the sessions. Also, what I linked before, it looks like cinnamon has the same problem and I think they use a different WM too. Anyway I gave you an up, hope someone finds it out.